# SIGABRT Xcode 4.2 issue

Tags: ios, xcode4.2, sigabrt

Since I've upgraded from xcode 3.1 to xcode 4.2, when I debug a program and for some reason I get a SIGABRT error (i.e. calling a method of an object that doesn't exist) Xcode shows the error in the main function of the program, instead of the line that is generating the SIGABRT.

Maybe I'm missing some kind of configuration in the debugger or in xcode? any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What did it for me, was something that I found [here](http://www.weston-fl.com/blog/?p=3089) that has to do with creating NSZombies

I'll at least copy the highlights:

1. Go to your project in Xcode 4
2. Environment variables can be set up in the Scheme editor (find Product -> Edit scheme… in menu bar):
3. Name the variable as NSZombieEnabled and set its value to YES.
4. Run your app in Debug mode. You likely get a … message sent
   to deallocated instance… message and the debugger stops at the line in error. This information leads to the problem.
5. When ready, disable NSZombieEnabled by changing YES to NO.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem for a long time and I found a solution just now. Don't know if it's the most kosher way, but at least it works for me. Basically you should create a global breakpoint (global meaning applying to all your projects).

Check out [this blog post](http://chanson.livejournal.com/171198.html), and [this tutorial on how to create symbolic breakpoints](https://devforums.apple.com/thread/68421). I myself created an Exception breakpoint (it catches `objc_exception_throw` too) this way:

[image: (for all exceptions)]

and then moved it to "User" breakpoints space:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the scheme you are using has breakpoints active. You can turn them on by hitting the button next to the scheme selector.

http://bit.ly/zuTnpF

Comment: Hi Raheel. They are in did turned ON. I've been reading around and it seems to be some kind of problem in xcode 4.2